# Ошибка в коде: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении

Tags: c++

Задача: По данным n отрезкам необходимо найти множество точек минимального размера, для которого каждый из отрезков содержит хотя бы одну из точек.

В первой строке дано число 1≤n≤100 отрезков. Каждая из последующих n строк содержит по два числа 0≤l≤r≤109, задающих начало и конец отрезка. Выведите оптимальное число m точек и сами m точек. Если таких множеств точек несколько, выведите любое из них.

Мое решение:

```
void swap(int *a1, int *a2, int M);
void sort(int **a, int N, int M);
void greedy(int **a, int *x, int N);

int main()
{
int **a;//двумерный массив отрезков
int N;
int M=2;
int *x;//одномерный массив точек

cout << "Enter N: "; //ввод количества отрезков
cin>>N;

x = new int[N]; //инициализация массива, который потом станет массивом точек
for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    x[i]=0;

a = new int *[N];
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    a[i] = new int [M];
//ввод концов отрезков    
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        cin >> a[i][j];
    }
}
//вывод до сортировки
cout <<endl << "Before sorting:" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        cout << std::setw(3) << a[i][j] << " ";
        cout << endl;
}


sort(a, N, M);//сортировка массива

//вывод после сортировки
cout << endl << "After sorting:" << endl;

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
        cout << setw(3) << a[i][j] << " ";

    cout << endl;
}
//вызов функции с жадным алгоритмом
greedy(a,x, N);

for (int i=0; i<=N; i++)
    cout<<x[i]<<' ';

system("pause");
return 0;
}


void swap(int *a1, int *a2, int M)//меняет 2 строки местами
{
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
{
    int temp = a1[i];
    a1[i] = a2[i];
    a2[i] = temp;
    }
}

void sort(int **a, int N, int M)//сортировка пузырьком отрезков по правой   точке 
{
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    for (int j = N - 1; j > i; j--)
        if (a[j - 1][1] >a[j][1])
            swap(a[j - 1], a[j], M);
}

void greedy(int **a, int *x,  int N)
{
int i=0;
int k=0;
while (i<=N)
{
    x[k]=a[i][1];
    i++;
    while ((x[k]>=a[i][0]) && (x[k]<=a[i][1]))
    {i++;}
    k++;
}

}
```

Но программа падает с ошибкой: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении. Может, кто видит, почему?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Опять задачи со степика из курса Алгоритмов. Ребят, вы же для себя учитесь, попробуйте сами разобраться.

Суть же проблемы очевидна: вы убежали за пределы массива. Я вижу три места, где это происходит:

```
// N - размер, последний индекс N-1, поэтому строго меньше N
while (i<=N)
```

тут аналогично:

```
for (int i=0; i<=N; i++)
```

тут чуть иначе:

```
// Думаете за пределами массива нули? 
// А кто обещает? 
// Там может быть любой мусор, поэтому убежать можно далеко. Проверяйте i тоже.
while ((x[k]>=a[i][0]) && (x[k]<=a[i][1]))
{i++;}
```

Ну и верните из `greedy` `k`, что бы таки узнать число точек.

И да, рекомендую для отрезка сделайть структуру с двумя полями: не будете париться с двумерным массивом, код станет более читаемым, а как следствие в таком коде легче искать ошибки. А ещё давать осмысленные имена переменным. Что мешает `x` назвать `dots` или `points`, а `a` - `lines`, я уже не говорю про страстное желание ручного управления памятью, вместо `std::vector`.

Ну и научитесь пользоваться отладчиками и профилировщиками типа Valgrind, они чуть ли не в сивол ткнут, где у вас ошибка.

Comment: Извините, не спал всю, спросонья забыл написать, где именно ошибка. Так вот, отладчик выдает:       Первый этап обработки исключения в "0x00b81644" в "stepic_greedy1.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0xfdfdfdfd".
Необработанное исключение в "0x00b81644" в "stepic_greedy1.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0xfdfdfdfd".
    Указывает на эту строку: while ((x[k]>=a[i][0]) && (x[k]<=a[i][1])).   Во вкладке "видимые" показывает, что проблемы с a[i]:   CXX0030: ошибка: невозможно вычислить выражение.

Comment: Я понимаю, что это то же самое, что вы и говорили, но я не очень понимаю, как в этом цикле while можно убежать за пределы массива.

Comment: А вы и не отвечайте на явно учебные задания кодом. А то так вы провоцируете остальных не решать самим, а спрашивать у вас.

Comment: @VladD, тут суть задачи в алгоритме, а не в языке. Хотя и не понимаю, почему человек пытается программировать на языке, которого не знает, там в курсе выбор языков сильно большой.
MasterSplinter, дальше подсказвыать не буду :)

Comment: @VladD, а почему вы решили, что я не хочу решать? Я написал уже свое решение, у меня вопрос по вполне конкретному месту. Я же не написал задачу, и не попросил ее решить за меня.

Comment: @MonahTuk Спасибо за помощь, подсказок еще не надо, уже разобрался) Действительно, глупая ошибка была.

Answer (score 1):

Вы выходите за пределы массива когда i = N, исправьте в циклах <= на <.

Comment: Хорошее замечание, исправил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

`cout`, `cin`, `system("pause")` работают с внешней средой - если проблема в них, закомментировать вызовы.

Но больше похоже на то, что где-то ошибка в размерах массивов и обращение к элементу за их пределами.

---

Рекомендую вам использовать отладчик и публиковать *все* подробности ошибки.

Comment: Этот косяк у меня уже отметили, извините, не спал всю, спросонья забыл написать, где именно ошибка. Так вот, отладчик выдает: Первый этап обработки исключения в "0x00b81644" в "stepic_greedy1.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0xfdfdfdfd". Необработанное исключение в "0x00b81644" в "stepic_greedy1.exe": 0xC0000005: Нарушение прав доступа при чтении "0xfdfdfdfd". Указывает на эту строку: while ((x[k]>=a[i][0]) && (x[k]<=a[i][1])). Во вкладке "видимые" показывает, что проблемы с a[i]: CXX0030: ошибка: невозможно вычислить выражение.

Comment: Как тут указали в одном из ответов, что в этом цикле возможен выход за пределы массива. Но я не очень понимаю, почему может убегать и как это исправить .